# New activity banner gets pushy with the question list

Tags: bug, design, live-refresh

The new activity banner sets the top margin of the question list:

```
$("#question-mini-list, #questions").prepend(w).css("margin-top", "0px")
```

but never unsets it, causing the question list to get permanently bumped down (the original margin is negative) after the first time the activity bar shows up:

> [image: question list before and after activity bar]

It should remove the margin it sets when the bar fades out on click, for Great <s>Justice</s> Consistency.

Relatedly, `.search-results` has `margin-top: 10px`, but this should actually be `-10px` if it's intended to match the other lists.